# How to throw an exeption, if a value is missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried this:

```
const a = null || throw new Error("value missing");
```

But I got an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'throw'

Does any syntactic sugar exist for this or is it necessary to use an `if` clause?

Comment: Yes, use an `if`. `throw` is a *statement* and cannot be mixed into an *expression*.

Comment: @deceze annoying

Comment: @deceze How exactly scope the __constant__ `a` correctly when using `if`?

Comment: if u want to be daring u can make it a iife `const a = null || (()=> {throw new Error("value missing")})();` which is kinda weird but u can do it just for fun

Comment: @AritraChakraborty annoying

Comment: @Teemu `const a = null || ...` doesn't make much sense to begin with…

Comment: Your line of code does not make sense to me... You are declaring a constant as `null` (meaning, it won't change and stay null), OR maybe if it has no value, throw an error?? But you are declaring it as `null`... What is this code supposed to achieve?

Comment: @deceze `null` is just the most simple example. In the real world the r-value is a slightly more complex evaluation.

Comment: Well, then: `const a = ...; if (!const) throw new Error;`. You *can* even write it on a single line, as shown here, if you have a shortage of lines and insist on it; you just can't make it a single expression.